# Magento: Add multiple configurations from configurable product at once to cart

Tags: php, magento, product

I have have a configurable product created with "color" configurable attribute. Also, this product has some custom options (like "size")

I need to add multiple configurations of product to cart from product view. The purchaser can add up to 5 products at once. One example:

In the product "T-shirt" page, customer sets this order

- 1 unit of Red size L
- 1 unit of Blue size S
- 3 units of Blue size XL

I've been looking for "Magento add multiple products to cart" and I found some topics, but all related to category page (products list). I do not expect anyone write a step by step on how to do, but if somebody can give me a link that talks about the subject it will help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: working on 1.9.1.0 CE http://codecanyon.net/item/magento-configurable-product-color-size-grid-view/9115520 (beware the licence, it is not that cheap!)